# how to add a property of type HttpPostedFileBase in entity framework code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first

I am working with ef-code first approach, here I need to add a property of type HttpPostedFileBase.

I am getting below error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot call Property for the
>   property 'myFile' on entity type 'TblEmployee' because it is
>   configured as a navigation property. Property can only be used to
>   configure scalar properties.'

```
public partial class TblEmployee 
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }     
    public HttpPostedFileBase myFile { get; set; }
}
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.EmployeeId);
    entity.ToTable("tblEmployee");    
    entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeId).HasColumnName("EmployeeID");
    entity.Property(e => e.myFile )
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasMaxLength(200)
                        .IsUnicode(false);
}
```

Comment: `HttpPostedFileBase ` should only be used on your presentation layer (view model). In your enity class you should use `byte[]` there.

Comment: If you are going to show the contents of the file in your app, probably want to store an extension, name with extension or mime type with your file so you know how to present it.

Comment: what is entity here?post entity

Comment: Decorate it with the [NotMapped] attribute